# Trying standard why of ASP.NET Core 5 Signalr and Angular but it is showing error in console .error : websocket faild to connect

Tags: websocket, signalr, asp.net-core-5.0, angular13

I'm trying to use SignalR in ASP.NET Core 5; I've added SignalR service in service configuration and also created a hub class and its method with Angular, which is also  configured as I saw on websites there codes similar but still getting below error please some help me:

> Error: Failed to start the connection:
> Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This Previous question was from me ,Actually from 4 days i was facing issue in signalr Configuration but the error issue Reason was Port Number Incidently i changed My port number from application properties (Debug Properties) but forgot to change the application path in angular signalR configuration which was not showing any cores issue and i was being confused for 4 days. << I changed angular signalR Configuration withUrl path to right path and issue resolved